# How to edit/open exact cell in the table

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

the table is  fxml.
Columns: Firstname, Lastname, Phone, Email
I would like to perfom mouse click at the column Email in order to edit exact Email.
The following code is working not properly, always open email to edit, not exact cell

```
 table.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? is this complete?

Comment: YEs this complete. I have fxml name Email and I want use only this column, and I not find in intertet how I can do it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to edit a column in a table view.  You can use a text field column, which will allow the entry of data when you click on it.  In this case, only the email column is editable.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXApplication7 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> tv = new TableView();
        TableColumn<Person, String> fCol = new TableColumn<>();
        TableColumn<Person, String> lCol = new TableColumn<>();
        TableColumn<Person, String> pCol = new TableColumn<>();
        TableColumn<Person, String> eCol = new TableColumn<>();

        tv.setEditable(true);
        tv.getColumns().addAll(fCol, lCol, pCol, eCol);

        fCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().firstName);
        lCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().lastName);
        pCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().phone);
        eCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().email);
        eCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new TextFieldTableCell<>());

        ObservableList<Person> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Person p = new Person();
        p.email.set("foo@bar.com");
        p.firstName.set("Tony");
        p.lastName.set("Stark");
        p.phone.set("(555) 555-1212");

        items.add(p);

        tv.setItems(items);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tv);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public class Person {
        StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty phone = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
```

sets the click handler for the whole `TableView` instead. This way you cannot distinguish between the columns that were clicked.

You should use the editing feature provided by `TableCell` instead:

```
// Simplified Person class
public class Person {

    private final StringProperty name;

    private final StringProperty email;

    public Person(String name, String email) {
        this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    }

    public final String getEmail() {
        return this.email.get();
    }

    public final void setEmail(String value) {
        this.email.set(value);
    }

    public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return this.name.get();
    }

    public final void setName(String value) {
        this.name.set(value);
    }

    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

```
TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Person("Darth Vader", "dad@empire.com"),
        new Person("James Bond", "bond007@mi6.gb")));
table.setEditable(true);

Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>> cellFactory = col
        -> new TableCell<Person, String>() {

            {
                // make cell itself editable
                setEditable(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void startEdit() {
                super.startEdit();
                // open dialog for input when the user edits the cell
                TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog(getItem());
                dialog.setGraphic(null);
                dialog.setHeaderText("Set new " + col.getText() + ".");
                dialog.setTitle("Edit " + col.getText());
                Optional<String> opt = dialog.showAndWait();
                if (opt.isPresent()) {
                    commitEdit(opt.get());
                } else {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(empty ? null : item);
            }

        };

TableColumn<Person, String> name = new TableColumn<>("name");
name.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().nameProperty());
name.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

TableColumn<Person, String> email = new TableColumn<>("email");
email.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().emailProperty());
email.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

table.getColumns().addAll(name, email);
```

Comment: It's code not use fxml scene, when I use SceneBuilder code another then I use JPanel

Comment: @AlexAs: I wonder where the line `table.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {` was placed then... Also it's easy to assemble the parts in the fxml, if you use a top-level class as `cellFactory`. Also last time I checked, SceneBuilder didn't allow you to choose the `cellValueFactory`/`cellFactory`, so if you only rely on fxmls that are produced by SceneBuilder you' won't be able to accomplish the task anyway...